# Invalid time zone 'UTC'

Tags: ubuntu, timezone

Listing the available timezones shows 'UTC'

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones
UTC
```

Setting it to UTC fails claiming UTC is "invalid".

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone UTC
Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'UTC'
```

This is on Ubuntu 19.10 (Google Cloud)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 19.10
Release:  19.10
Codename: eoan
```

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 24):

## `Etc/UTC`

You are missing [Area code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area) defined in the official [*tz database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

The time zone format is `Area/Location`. For most zones, the Area is a continent and the Location is a major city. For example, `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Tunis`, `Asia/Tokyo`, and `Pacific/Auckland`. Peruse [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Administrative zones have a special area: `Etc`. Therefore, the correct name for [*Coordinated Universal Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is `Etc/UTC`.

Comment: When running `timedatectl list-timezones`, all of the other time zones are in the format Area/Location. The output of ` timedatectl list-timezones | grep UTC` is just "UTC".  Who thought it was a good idea to do that instead of making the output `Etc/UTC`?

Comment: @RonJohn In 2014, Lennart [added this code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/7568345034f2890af745747783c5abfbf6eccf0f#diff-4bd8a24c1e0ebf379eaeed06d60a7083R838), which explicitly lists "UTC".

Comment: @RolandIllig why am I utterly and completely, 100% **not** surprised???

Comment: What I am surprised about is that even after 5 years, there is no bug report about this topic. I also cannot find any unit tests for this code in the commit. 

Comment: @RonJohn: My system (tzdata 2019c-2) has `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` with no area prefix, and I see glibc's own source tree containing tests with `setenv ("TZ", "UTC", 1)` implying that it is a valid value... so the question isn't why timedatectl lists the name, but rather why it _rejects_ the name.

Comment: @grawity why? Lennart Poettering, that's why?  (He must have an amazing collection of serious blackmail material to have been able to propagate as much crap has he's made, with zero pushback from RH.)

Comment: Does not look like that's the problem: `$ timedatectl set-timezone Etc/UTC` gives
`Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'Etc/UTC'`

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug in your distro, they should package /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC unconditionally, even if no other timezone data is installed. Please report this to your distribution.

Comment: Not sure how open Google is for feedback. I just installed `tzdata` and now it works.

Comment: Google isn't responsible for Ubuntu.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: But Google decides what packages are installed on their images.